# Corrupted Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Using my Google Fu, I am not finding any information on how to troubleshoot a corrupted Azure virtual machine. It has been working fine for almost 8 months and I have had to redeploy it 1-2 before because it would not start.

Any helpful pointers or point me to some troubleshooting steps please.

[image]

Comment: wow, I've never seen that, I'd suggest you contact support. redeploy probably wont help in this case

Comment: This is my first time experiencing a corrupted state and I am def concerned I won't be able able to reinstate it correctly. TY I will try and contacting support.

Comment: The only other article online that I have found is more of a blog on what likely happened if you had a corrupted or failed virtual hard disk [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2009/01/07/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-virtual-hard-disk/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2009/01/07/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-virtual-hard-disk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a redeploy of my Azure virtual machine and perhaps did not wait long enough before shooting off the support request and creating this post as I am able to access my VM again. I received the following troubleshooting steps from Azure support professional so I am sharing here in case anyone else runs into these issues:

> To over come this issue we can proceed to run a series of PowerShell scripts to force update the actual status of the VM on Azure backend, please follow this process:
>
> - To easily complete this, we can launch Azure PowerShell, please go to:
>     https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell
> - Click on “Launch Cloud Shell” button:

[image: Launch Cloud Shell]

> - On the newly open window, click on “PowerShell” link:

[image: Powershell]

> - Then you can run the script, as is, line per line:
>
> $vmName = "(Your VM NAME)"
>
> $rgName = "(Your resource Group)"
>
> $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
>
> update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VM $vm
>
> - This should bring the VM to healthy or ready state.
> - Please let me know the outcome of the PS command, if successful try to start the VM.
> - If it still shows as “corrupted” please share with support a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Some other Azure troubleshooting pages given to me are:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/allocation-failure-classic
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/allocation-failure
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/restart-resize-error-troubleshooting